# How do you go back to an older version of dependencies if the location or the npm registry has migrated to a new location?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, registry, yarnpkg

How do you go back to an older version if the locations of a git dependency or the npm registry itself has migrated to a new location?

Occasionally there is a need to change the location where a git repo is hosted. Or, if maintaining a private npm registry, the URL of the registry may change.

Since their URLs are checked in as part of `package.json` or `yarn.lock` (or npm equivalent).

How do you deal with the case where you need to build an older version but the location has changed?

Is there a possibility to overwrite the resolved URL before the fetch occurs?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using Artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) and follow this steps:

1. Create a remote repo with the external repo or public registry that you need (probably you have this URL in your registry or in your dependencies inside the package.json).
2. Create a virtual NPM repo in Artifactory and add to this virtual repo the remote repo created in the steep 1.
3. Replacing the default registry with your new virtual repository with this command:

   ```
   npm config set registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/your-npm-virtual-repo-name
   ```
4. Remove server links and replace with only the dependency name and version like:

   ```
       "dependency-name1": "0.0.1",
       "dependency-name2": "0.0.1",
   ```

And publish your projects without server links, It's a bad practice to have the URL of the repo inside the dependencies in the package.json.

More info here: [Npm Registry with Jfrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-Overview)

Comment: My package.json does not have full URLs. However yarn.lock has to the fully resolved dependency URL. [yarn.lock is checked into source control](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/#toc-check-into-source-control). If I want to checkout a particular change and the registry has changed to something other than what's in the committed yarn.lock, how do I point to the new registry? Manually edit yarn.lock?